# Cypress: Need help in dynamically locating element

Tags: cypress

I have the below code,
Suppose of second element is not there, my script will fail. Is there a way to dynamically change the .eq values?

i.e if second assertion is commented then the third statement should take .eq(3) instead of .eq(5)

```
cy.get('[data-testid=financials-overview-balance-sheet-card]').within(() => {
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(1).should("have.text",finYear[0])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(3).should("have.text",finYear[1])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(5).should("have.text",finYear[2])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(7).should("have.text",finYear[3])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(9).should("have.text",finYear[4])
})
```

```
cy.get('[data-testid=financials-overview-balance-sheet-card]').within(() => {
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(1).should("have.text",finYear[0])
       // cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(3).should("have.text",finYear[1])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(5).should("have.text",finYear[2])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(7).should("have.text",finYear[3])
        cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').eq(9).should("have.text",finYear[4])
})
```

Comment: Do you have an array somewhere in your test script - `finYear[0]` ?

Comment: Yes its finYear[0] is an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always the 2nd header element that's not there, you can adjust the `finYear` array

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=financials-overview-balance-sheet-card]').within(() => {

  cy.get('table[type="financial"] th').its('length').then(th_count => {

    const expected = [...finYear];
    if (th_count < finYear.length *2) {
      expected.splice(1, 1);     // remove the 2nd answer
    } 

    for (let i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
      cy.get('table[type="financial"] th').eq((i*2)+1)
        .should("have.text", expected[i])
    }
  })
})
```

If you just want to answer the question **Are all headers in finYear**,

use `finYear.includes()`

```js
cy.get('[data-testid=financials-overview-balance-sheet-card]').within(() => {

  cy.get('table[type="financial"] th').each(($th, index) => {
    
    if (index % 2 === 0) return;  // ignore even columns

    cy.wrap($th).invoke('text')
      .should(headerText => finYear.includes(headerText))

  })
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I will go with the first solution, because header is spread across in multiple arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `each()` directly to check the inner text of all the elements one by one -

```
 cy.get('table[type="financial"] thead th').each(($ele, index) => {
    expect($ele).to.have.text(finYear[index])
})
```